How to add a Icon Button to the ToolBar that can be clicked?
I am just getting into .NET and MAUI.
As the question states, I am trying to add a a Icon Button to the ToolBar that can be clicked.
At this moment i have a ToolbarItem with text that can be clicked.
I have also a Icon. For icons, the ToolbarItem class comes with an IconImageSource property, which is of type ImageSource. This means that we can also use a FontImageSource to provide the icon for the button based on a custom font.
I have two problems with the Icon Button.
First: I am not able to change the Size. It does not matter which value i put into the Size the Icon does not change.
Second: Is it possible to introduce the Clicked event like in a Button or ToolbarItem?
Thanks in advance for some help.
Follows the xaml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    
    

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        
        <ToolbarItem Text="Second Page"               
                     Clicked="GotoSecondPage" />

        <ToolbarItem >
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialIconsOutlined-Regular"
                                 Glyph="&#xe5e1;"
                                 Color="Black"
                                 Size="120" />
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>

        </ToolbarItem>
        

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


    <Shell.TitleView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Welcome to MAUI"
                   FontFamily="Strande2"
                   TextColor="White"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HeightRequest="50"
                   FontSize="Medium" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>


    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0"
                             Spacing="15">
            <Label Text="HOME PAGE"
                   Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                   SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
            <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                   HeightRequest="130"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label Text="Hello, World!"
                   Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                   SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Button x:Name="CounterBtn"
                    Text="Click me"
                    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                    Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

            <Button x:Name="GoToPageTwoButton"
                    Text="Go to Page Two"
                    Clicked="GotoSecondPage"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>


use the Clicked event on the ToolbarItem as you are already doing

To change the size of the icon, edit the 'BaseSize' property in your project file: 

@Jmie The OP is explicitly talking about a font icon using <FontImageSource, there's no image file that is processed by the resizetizer.

Consindering that the Size property of the FontImageSource applies to the text size of the symbol, 120 is very large. Have you tried smaller values between 20 and 30? For me, those values usually work well. Can you show a screenshot of what it looks like? And which platform is this on?

I tried for the Size 20, 30, 40........ Nothing change the size. I put a screenshot

I tried out on a Android Emulator and there the Size of the icon change. On a Windows Machine it stays static and does not change the Size.

Then it's probably a bug. Have you checked the issues in the MAUI GitHub repo?

Yes it is a bug. I checked the issues in the MAUI GirHub and there are already several situation talking about this. But no solution for this problem.

You can follow this similar issue in MAUI github: Icon Button in ToolBar does not change the Size In Windows Plarform.
